# In C# is there a way to override a private or public function through a plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, overriding, member-functions

I have an application that loads plugins. I have a plugin that has complete access to a form instance. If I have a function in a form that needs to be overridden, but is not a virtual function, is there another way to override it?

Here is a very generic example:

```
//Form I am modifying
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public int myVariable1;
    public int myVariable2;

    //Constructor and other methods here

    private void setVar(int replacementValue)
    {
        myVariable1 = replacementValue;
    }
}
```

...then in a separate dll...

```
//My plugin
public class MyPlugin : IMyPluginBase
{
    MyForm theForm; //Reference to the form in the main application

    //Constructor and other methods here

    private void setVar(int replacementValue)
    {
        theForm.myVariable2 = replacementValue;
    }
}
```

In this example the function in the form sets 'myVariable1', but the 'setVar' function in the plugin sets 'myVariable2'.

So, the question is, in the case of this example, can I replace/override the form's 'setVar' function with the one in the plugin? Maybe with messages or reflection?

Comment: There are ways to accomplish this with the Profiling API, but you're asking for headaches if you go down that road.  The whole notion of a plugin that can 'do anything' is inimical to the principle of insulation, a principle which serves an important function in maintaining developer sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. You cannot "replace" or overide private non-virtual methods in C#.**

The C# language (and .NET runtime) don't support dynamic replacement of methods in the manner you describe. Very few languages support this capability, to my knowledge (I believe that SmallTalk and Objective-C both do).

If this is the only place in your application where you need this kind of extensibility, you can achieve it through an interface, delegate, or inhertance+virtual methods. Any of these approaches could work ... which one you choose depends on what kind of extensibility you desire.

If you expect to have many such extensibility points in your app, then you should probably take a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmef.codeplex.com%2F&ei=JFz9TMSUH8uQnwey5MnICg&usg=AFQjCNEF0AYj2G7YNMZtb7vkj_RgJmptVg&sig2=gPgyw3ReTaDxgJCsi_4QQg) (MEF). It provides a Microsoft-supported model for creating plug-in architectures using patterns and technique that work well in .NET.

Comment: Can you use MEF to write plugins in such a way that the main application knows nothing of the plugins? We have an application that loads plugins, but knows nothing of their type or methods, only of the common 'IPlugin' interface we have defined. We need to keep it this way.

Comment: @Mike Webb: MEF does require that apps that will support extensibility expose their extension points. This means that the ways in which you can extend the original application are constrained by what the author choose to allow (you can't make arbitrary changes to how the original code operates). However, the application doesn't have to know about the extensions that it will operate with in advance. It only has to provide the extension points up front. Based on what you describe, I think MEF would likely be a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is not marked as [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) or part of an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) that your class implements there's exactly 0 chance you would be able to override it. No plugin, no reflection, no nothing, simply forget about it or use some other dynamic language but not C#.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no.  What you can do, however, is give your form a copy of the IMyPluginBase, and have Form.setVar() call out to MyPluginBase.SetVar().

The code will look something like this:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public int myVariable1;
    public int myVariable2;

    public IMyPluginBase MyPlugin;

    //Constructor and other methods here

    private void setVar(int replacementValue)
    {
        MyPlugin.setVar(replacementValue);
        //myVariable1 = replacementValue;
    }
}

public class MyPlugin : IMyPluginBase
{
    MyForm theForm; //Reference to the form in the main application
    public void setVar(int replacementValue)
    {
        theForm.myVariable2 = replacementValue;
    }
}
```

Note that setVar() will need to be defined in IMyPluginBase.

Comment: I should point out that this exact implementation will only allow you to have a single plugin per form.  A List of IMyPluginBase on the form will get around this.